# National Sports Wheels? What model?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I'm trying to ID an older road bike, I think perhaps 80's but not really sure. I can't seem to find much info about even the brand itself - **National Sports Wheels** (Passaic, NJ) (Made In Taiwan)

Searching that brand just brings ups a few results for some older BMX bikes, nothing road bike at all. Also the frame has a sticker saying '12 Speed' but is actually a 10 speed - not sure if that sticker was added by someone or if the gears were changed. Serial number on the bottom bracker is **S885278**

**Whole Bike**:
[image]

**Brand Sticker**:
[image]

I've had this in my shed for quite some time and its a hand me down, so no idea about the original owner or anything like that. I'm starting riding again so planning on refinishing the frame and maybe rebuilding with some modern components, but really curious that I can't find anything on the brand.

Comment: Late 70s to early 80s.  Pretty generic.  Probably not department store, but not real high class either.  Don't refinish the frame -- you'll never be done.

Comment: I've refinished two other frames before, it is a lot of work so not 100% sure I'm going that route. Never attempted component upgrades though, some things seem pretty straightforward but not sure if that will turn into a poor choice ha

Comment: The bike appears to be a ROPA (ridden once -- put away), so there should be no need to change anything (other than the tires) if the bearings aren't seized, etc.  Do note that this bike is pre-indexing, and the rear cluster is about as generic/primitive as they come.

Comment: Its definitely gotten some use, but is in decent shape for its age - nothing is seized up, but the brakes are super mushy/not strong, and yeah the non indexing shifting is tough, hence my desire for modern setups... at the very least I'm going to give it a good cleaning before I reassemble and ride again the 2nd/last ride I took was a bit scary haha. Some downhill wobbles and poor braking abilities

Comment: Yeah, the brake pads are likely in need of replacement.  And changing to indexed shifting will be tricky at best.

Comment: Is it feasible to replace the entire groupset with a modern one, like a Shimano Tiagra or something? I should be able to modify the rear hub spacing enough, and if I was replacing the entire cassette and everything then it should match the shifters (I would think). I'm not sure if the bottom bracket would fit modern stuff or how that would work exactly though

Comment: You'd probably have to replace the rear hub, and might as well replace the entire wheel.  Probably a "standard" derailer will fit, but that depends on how the current one is "hung".  I'd not bother with trying to go indexed on the BB.

Comment: @JonathanElwell "old frame, new mechanicals" would be a separate question.  Start by just riding this bike for a while, do the bare minimum to get it safe.  Then later when lockdowns are relaxed, you'll have hours of riding on this bike to know what you like and don't like.   If you had a donor bike then a swap of the groupset would be more practical, but droppign big money on new groupset should be a later-decision.  Just ride for a while (but be aware 80s brakes are not that great even after pad replacement.)  BTW - *SUPER-NICE BIKE!*

Answer (score 1):

National sport wheels was made by a company in the UK called BITD inc. A lot of frames were made in Taiwan. They distributed the NSW from Passaic, NJ.

I have had a hard time trying to find year and models of these bikes. I have an NSW 20" bmx bike I assembled from just the frame. The frame was found in a old, abandoned Schwinn shop in AZ and was never assembled until I got it.

Comment: I have also come to the conclusion that that BITD inc. Was also the maker of the Giant name brand bikes? I did some research a while back when I first got my bike and came across this this info somewhere on the web. Guess I should be saving the sites I get info from for future reference.

Comment: Do you mean that Giant was the contract manufacturer for BITD?

Comment: Giant was established in 1972 in Dajia, Taichung County in Taiwan (now part of Taichung City), by King Liu and several friends.[who?] A major breakthrough came in 1977 when Giant's chief executive, Tony Lo, negotiated a deal with Schwinn to begin manufacturing bikes as an OEM, manufacturing bicycles to be sold exclusively under other brand names as a private label. As bike sales increased in the U.S., and after workers at the Schwinn plant in Chicago went on strike in 1980, Giant became a key supplier, making more than two-thirds of Schwinn bikes by the mid-1980s, representing 75% of sales.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMX

Comment: I believe Giant was the contract manufacturer for BITD who made the National sport wheels brand.

Comment: In the UK, BMX was a craze which took off in the early 1980s, specifically 1982 and 1983, when the BMX bike became the must-have bicycle for children and teenagers.